# PrimeNg ConfirmationService - Error NG6002

Tags: angular, primeng, ng-modules

I'm building my Application Form and need a confirmation pop-up to use. but I'm getting a build error -

> error Ng6002 - Appears in the NgModule.imports of appModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class. export declare class ConfirmationService {

my code is the following:

- app.module.ts

  ```
  .......
  import {ConfirmationDialogModule} from 'primeng/confirmationdialog';
  import {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/api';
  .......

  @NgModule({
      declaration: [....],
      imports: [
          ....,
          ConfirmationDialogModule,
          ConfirmationService,
          .....
      ]
  })
  ```

then I'm simply using it in my component

````
```
import {ConfirmationDialogModule} from 'primeng/confirmationdialog';
import {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-form,
   templateUrl: './form.component.ts',
   styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
});

export class FormComponent implements onInit {
   .....
   .....
   constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService){ }
   ...
   ...
   ...

   submitForm() {
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
         message: "Test Confirm",
         accept: () => { this.router.navigate['./somewhere'] }
   })
  }
}
```
````

I have **importHelper: true** & **enableIvy: false** I deleted the Node_Modules and installed, but nothing seems to be working!!

Any Ideas?

Comment: You don't add services to the `imports` array in a module. Those belong in the `providers` array in the module.

Comment: Oh boy.... that completely went over my head for the last hour. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation Service is a service. If you want to use it, you should declare it NOT in "imports:[]". You have to declare it in the "providers:[]"

So your code should look like this:
app.module.ts

```js
import {ConfirmationDialogModule} from 'primeng/confirmationdialog';
import {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/api';
.....
    
@NgModule({
    declaration: [.....],
    imports: [
        ConfirmationDialogModule,
        .....
    ],
    providers: [
        ConfirmationService,
        .....
    ]
})
```